# recursively mark all files in a directory as modified without changing file content

Tags: command-line, files, timestamps, recursive

I am on a system which deletes files which haven't been modified in 30 days. I need some way to preserve important files by marking them as being recently modifed. What is the best way I can do this? Something like `for d in *; do; cat $d > $d ; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cd` to that directory, then use this command to mark only the files :

```
find . -type f -exec touch {} \;
```

or this command to mark even the directories :

```
find . -exec touch {} \;
```

After the execution, the files (and folders if you choose the 2nd command) will be marked that they were just changed, and their content won't be changed.

The advantage of this command that it will go recursive, even the subdirectories and the files under those subdirectories will be marked as changed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `touch`.

```
NAME
       touch - change file timestamps

SYNOPSIS
       touch [OPTION]... FILE...

DESCRIPTION
       Update  the  access  and modification times of each FILE to the current
       time.
```

Comment: I'm struggling to incorporate this into a truly recursive routine

Comment: No need to use recursion (explicitly). Just use `find` and pipe to output to `xargs touch`.

Comment: @kilojoules You had the `find` command in your question. Find what you want, then `-exec touch {} +`.

Comment: `touch` works, provided the admins are not sneaky bastards and use other means than the modification time to determine if the file has changed. For example, they could compute the hash of a file and compare it to a previously computed hash value.